# What can't this PDF be parsed by PDF parsing packages?

Tags: node.js, pdf-parsing

I have a PDF document that I'm attempting to parse into text. The document is part of the public domain of non-profit financial documents and is safe to share.

[Sample page on Google Storage](https://storage.googleapis.com/hunterhods-random-stuff/sample-one-page.pdf)

I've attempted to parse the document using a common NPM package called [pdf-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse), but it doesn't output any text.

JavaScript code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');

let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('./sample-one-page.pdf');

pdf(dataBuffer).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.numpages);
    console.log(data.numrender);
    console.log(data.info);
    console.log(data.metadata); 
    console.log(data.version);
    console.log(data.text); 
});
```

The script accurately detects the number of pages and all of the other metadata, but it doesn't parse the text. The output of running this script is below.

```
1
1
{
  PDFFormatVersion: '1.3',
  IsAcroFormPresent: false,
  IsXFAPresent: false,
  Title: 'PDF TIFF Wrapper',
  Author: 'Awesome Donald',
  Creator: 'ServiceFileCopy',
  Producer: 'macOS Version 13.3.1 (Build 22E261) Quartz PDFContext',
  CreationDate: "D:20230504152855Z00'00'",
  ModDate: "D:20230504152855Z00'00'"
}
null
1.10.100
```

I've verified that the script works with other PDF documents and I've also replicated the issue with a Python library for PDF parsing as well (https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/).

Is there something about this document that prevents text extraction?

Comment: "Title: 'PDF TIFF Wrapper'" is your clue (or just zoom in).

Comment: Ah I see, so OCR is the only real avenue to parsing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's just a PDF wrapper around a TIFF image. Didn't realize that until Dave pointed it out.